# Pattern matching higher-kinded parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, higher-kinded-types

I have a domain model with an ADT with 4 subcases, e.g.

```
sealed trait Param

case class A(...) extends Param
case class B(...) extends Param
case class C(...) extends Param
case class D(...) extends Param
```

And various type parameterised on this Param, e.g.

```
case class Config[T <: Param](...)
case class Parser[T <: Param](...)
case class Price[T <: Param](...)
```

I would love to be able to pattern match each of those:

```
val config: Config[T] = ??? 
//Assuming T <: Param, as defined above
config match {
  case confA: Config[A] => 
  case confB: Config[B] => 
  case confC: Config[C] => 
  case confD: Config[D] => 
}
```

But as we know type erasure makes this a pain...

Do notice though that I always need to match a higher-kinded `F[T <: Param].`

Any neat ideas? I have seen shapeless typeable, but not sure it how I could use it in my case. Switching to typelevel scala (which I think solves type parameter matching, woohoo) is not an option.

Any neat ideas people? :D

EDIT: 
Here is an approach I tried but run into compiler issues:

```
sealed trait Param

case class A() extends Param 
case class B() extends Param
case class C() extends Param
case class D() extends Param

sealed trait ForParam[F[T <: Param], T <:Param] {
  def value: F[T]
}
case class ForParamA[F[_]](value: F[A]) extends ForParam[F, A]
case class ForParamB[F[_]](value: F[B]) extends ForParam[F, B]
case class ForParamC[F[_]](value: F[C]) extends ForParam[F, C]
case class ForParamD[F[_]](value: F[D]) extends ForParam[F, D]

object ForParam {
  case class Example[T <: Param](f: T => String)

  val exampleFormParam: ForParam[Example, _] = ???
  //The below does not compile:
  //  [error]      constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  //  [error]       found   : ForParamD[F]
  //  [error]       required: ForParam[ForParam.Example,_$2] where type _$2
//  I think I run into issue related to https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6069
  exampleFormParam match {
    case ForParamA(value) =>
    case ForParamB(value) =>
    case ForParamC(value) =>
    case ForParamD(value) =>
  }

}
```

Comment: Match on config.something, which has the type you want :

    config.param match { 
    case a: A => ...
    case b:B => ...
    } Since Param is a sealed trait, it looks pretty safe

Comment: That is true, but only in cases were I has a concrete value in there, and not e.g. a function. In my case, the contained types are usually not types of type `Param`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, since I understand Config[T <: Param] as indicating that the contained types are necessarily subtypes of Param, and hence enumerable in a match clause ? I'm afraid I haven't understood correctly your need then !

Comment: No worries, I know it is a bit complex :) 
E.g. `Parser[T]` contains effectively a function of `String => Try[T]`.
`Config[T]` just so happens to contains a `Price[T]`, which is a practically `T => Money`.
So I don't have access to concrete value of type `T` inside my type containers.

Comment: @C4stor I made an adit with an idea that maybe highlights what I am after.

Comment: It's clear now, but the downside is I no longer have an idea ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost bound for type parameter in `ForParamA` etc.

The following code compiles:

```
  sealed trait Param

  case class A() extends Param
  case class B() extends Param
  case class C() extends Param
  case class D() extends Param

  sealed trait ForParam[F[_ <: Param], T <: Param] {
    def value: F[T]
  }
  case class ForParamA[F[_ <: Param]](value: F[A]) extends ForParam[F, A]
  case class ForParamB[F[_ <: Param]](value: F[B]) extends ForParam[F, B]
  case class ForParamC[F[_ <: Param]](value: F[C]) extends ForParam[F, C]
  case class ForParamD[F[_ <: Param]](value: F[D]) extends ForParam[F, D]

  object ForParam {
    case class Example[T <: Param](f: T => String)

    val exampleFormParam: ForParam[Example, _] = ???
    exampleFormParam match {
      case ForParamA(value) => ???
      case ForParamB(value) => ???
      case ForParamC(value) => ???
      case ForParamD(value) => ???
    }

  }
```

Comment: Good spot, thanks! Unfortunately, Intellij resolves the `value` as `Any[A]` / `Any[B]` etc which doesn't even make sense since Any is parameterless and so it reduces a bit the practical value, but still works :)